# Do I really need a relation table in my case?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a module. I build an interface where user can assign the module to groups. 
Lets say currently I have 3 groups. In the UI the user would choose all 3 groups to assign the module to them. For examle in a multiple selectbox.

The intention of the user is to assign the module to ALL groups.

I guess I would need a many to many relation table. My source code would execute a sql query to insert 3 entries.

But wait. What if two weeks later the admin adds a new group... In the relation table are only 3 entries. And the user wonders why the module is not assigned to the new added group.

What would be an elegant solution? I need definite to update the relation table, or I make a new column  -called, lets say "groups"-  in my module table where I add the assigned groupsIds in this format: "1;2;7;15" or the keyword "All". 
The advantage would be that with the keyword "All" I could know in my code that the module is assigned to all groups.
With the relation table I do not have this option. In addition I do not need to assign a group to a module. I just need to assign a module to groups.
In my opinion I do not need a relation table in this case.

What would you say? Or do you have another approach?

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth doing well.  Normalize your database and write your UI accordingly.

Comment: I would use the relation table except that if a module have a relation with all existing groups you just insert 1 row like `[moduleID; 'ALL']`.
That way you won't have to deal with splitting the string in the `group`column.

Comment: Set a foreign key 'module' in the groups table

Comment: Don't add stuff like "All" or null or similar as a relation key with semantic meaning in the database. Instead handle in your UI where you create new data to also insert relevant/needed data in the association table. It's better to allow the database to use referential integrity and ease of join statements than having to do such logic - will give you best performance, best maintainability and best data integrity

Comment: Your first problem is that you are considering teh datbase as an afterthought to the UI. What the UI wil do or not do is irrelevant to the correct design for the database. You need to think in database normalization terms to deisgn the table structure not in terms of what your UI is going to do.

Answer (score 0):

To make a many-to-many relation, you need a relation table.

To use a solution like putting comma separated values in a field to make multiple relations only works if you fetch data from separate tables in separate queries, when you need to use that to join the data in the database, it becomes very complicated very fast.

In a relation table you could use a `null` value to mean "all". In this example the modules 1 and 2 are members of the group 1 only, and the module 3 is a member of all groups:

```
ModuleId GroupId
-------- -------
       1       1
       2       1
       3    null
```

To fetch data for groups using a relation like that you would use a query like:

```
select
    g.GroupName,
    m.ModuleName
from
    Groups g
    inner join GroupModules gm on gm.GroupId is null or gm.GroupId = g.GroupdId
    inner join Modules m on m.ModuleId = gm.ModuleId
```

---

Another alternative is to use the relation table as usual, and add a property on the module that it's a member of all groups. When you add a new group, you would also add records in the relation table for all modules that are members of all groups. Example (in T-SQL):

```
create procedure Group_Add
  @GroupName varchar(50)
as

set nocount on

declare @id int

insert into Groups (
  GroupName
) values (
  @GroupName
)

set @id = scope_identity()

insert in GroupModules (
  GroupId,
  ModuleId
)
select
  @id, ModuleId
from
  Modules
where
  IsInAllGroups = 1
```

Comment: NULL usually means unknown values. Putting business logic into NULL and such a join structure - while possible - will likely create issues with maintainability and chances are you'll get poor execution plan for your query due to parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

The typical database pattern for this is 3 tables, Module, Group, GroupModule. That is how many to many relationships are properly handled in database design.

How to get the data populated is a problem for your UI. You can indeed have a pull down list that includes the word all for them to use in choosing the groups a module will be associated with. It can even be the default. What you do is write code to interpret ALL to insert one record for every group.

NOw if you are adding groups as well as modules, you also need a process to make sure that when a group is added all those which shoudl have all groups get added to the new group. Personally I would put an IS_ALL flag on the Module table to make this easier. Then you know which moduels have been selected for all groups. You will need to make sure that if someone goes back and changes the module to specificgroups instead of all that this field is updated.